# Why do I need to use CSS when I can just use Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

Context:
I am not new to programming, but I am new to front end development. That is, my background is mainly in scientific computing, and I now am building a basic web application.

Main:
I am starting from the ground up using Svelte/SvelteKit. I have a basic understanding of JS/TS/CSS/HTML, at least syntactically. Recently, I have run into the following issue.

I want to use custom colors/custom variable names for these colors (e.g., blue_light, blue_dark, which I have defined in another file and imported into my main +page.svelte) that match the specific pantone colors of the brand, plus it keeps things more organized for the team.

What I am seeking is a way to change several different colors of the web page at once. For example, the colors of link and visited text.

I *could* go through one-by-one and set each one under , but this is slow and prone to errors, obviously.

Instead, I thought I could set a CSS block to do exactly that, something like as follows:

```
<style>
    a.link {
        color: custom_color
    }
</style>
```

where `custom_color` is defined somewhere in `<script>`. My intuition was that I could pass a JavaScript variable to `<style>` with Svelte, because I can do so in `<main>` with curly brace syntax. I have done some digging, and it doesn't seem like there's an easy way to get what I am seeking, so it seems like I will have to rely on some method that utilizes `document.getElementsByName()` in Javascript.

All of this leads me to my question: What is the point of CSS, when I can manipulate everything with JavaScript? CSS does not seem very useful if I cannot pass variables to it. Is this a bottleneck of Svelte? Am I missing something obvious?

I have looked into JQuery to manipulate the page more concisely, but this does not lead me to understanding why CSS is necessary when page manipulation can just be handled with JavaScript.

edit:

For anyone that's in a similar spot, just use sass/scss. I created a theme.scss file that I can import and use in any of my svelte pages. You'll also want to set `lang='sass'` in `<style>`.

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/when-to-use-css-vs.-javascript/#:~:text=CSS%20parses%20and%20renders%20faster,a%20page%20to%20screeching%20halt.

Comment: You can make classes for the different colors and conditionally apply them, you can use css variables with svelte ([example](https://svelte.dev/repl/4b1c649bc75f44eb9142dadc0322eccd?version=3.6.7)), or you can directly put the color on the style attribute of the link

Comment: CSS and JS are very different languages, and just because JS can be used to set styles that would normally be in a CSS file, it doesn't invalidate the existence or use cases for CSS. I couldn't even begin to imagine how awful it would be to write a full website without CSS, while instead having it styled with JS... That's insanity to me (although it can be done with different methodologies like React, etc.) Your example is also a valid one; using a JS (or other language like PHP, C#, etc.) variable inside a `<style>` element is a commonplace occurrence in web development.

Comment: I have seen this example, but the workflow doesn't make sense to me. Isn't it more natural to want a variable defined in JS that is then used in a CSS block that is then applied to the appropriate HTML elements? Why would I want an element to be that color first before "zooming out" to CSS, which then reapplies it to other HTML elements? It does not seem like a natural workflow to me.

Comment: Yes I understand that CSS is used to set many many different properties. What I mean is that in this [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/4b1c649bc75f44eb9142dadc0322eccd?version=3.6.7), it seems that there must be some HTML element that utilizes the JS variable first, and then that JS variable "color" is then parsed to the CSS variable "--theme-color" within the declaration of that HTML element (<div>). I'm not sure why this is desirable over a system where I could just assign a JS directly in a CSS block, and not have to use it in an HTML element first.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! So less of an overarching question about CSS, and more for this specific use case; sorry about that. But yeah, looking at that example, simply using JS makes more sense to me. This could be done with an `onchange` handler on the `<input>`, or an Event Listener for that input, that simply sets the `<p>` element (all, or that specific one) color based on the value from `<input type="color"/>`. Using CSS there doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me at all really... It's interesting that you _can_ do that, but "So preoccupied if they could, they didn't stop to think if they should" 

Comment: Thanks for the thorough replies! Like I said, I am new to the front-end world, so I'll go ahead and ask the following as well. Frameworks like SASS and Tailwind don't happen to improve the interoperability between CSS and JS/TS, do they?

Comment: TBH, I have limited experience with JS/TS in this context, so I can't really say for sure. I do find that Tailwind is powerful, but complicated and repetitive, unless you can figure out a good way to extrapolate some of that repetition. For example using Laravel (PHP) + Tailwind, I wrote a PHP Theme helper that sets classes on HTML elements like `class="rounded-md shadow-sm {{ $theme->__('something') }}"`, where `__('something')` equates to a reusable set of Tailwind Classes for colors. Something similar could be done with JS/TS, but different due to PHP being server-side and JS being client.

Comment: True, You can manipulate the CSS styling using JavaScript. Then why use CSS? When you are using external CSS stylesheets, your browser can cache them to increase your application performance and efficiency. So, an answers is performance and efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Styles are preprocessed and compiled to separate CSS assets, this would simply not be possible if they had dynamic parts.

In general CSS should concern itself with styling/layout and JS with state/logic. This makes it easier to know where what should go/can be found and easier to read. Also there are many things you just cannot do in JS at all and vice versa, the languages are designed for their specific roles.

> CSS does not seem very useful if I cannot pass variables to it. Is this a bottleneck of Svelte? Am I missing something obvious?

In general you just don't have to. You set state, e.g. classes and attributes, and all the necessary styling or layout changes that state should entail happen in CSS. If you want to do everything "in code' you are probably thinking about problems the wrong way; Svelte has some limitations here but they really don't matter much if styling is approach the right way.

When it really is necessary, you also can pass variables by using the `style` attribute, setting [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) which can be accessed in CSS. This can, for example, be necessary to move elements like popups around, when layout cannot be fully calculated in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your question kind of does not make sense since javascript does not have any feature to control how a document should look. Only two things can control how a document should look: CSS and (the now less commonly used) HTML properties.

CSS is the main mechanism in modern web development for controlling rendering sytles. CSS properties such as `margin`, `color`, `background-image` and `font-size` control how elements should look.

There are three ways of specifying CSS styles:

1. In the element `"style"` property:

   ```
    <span id="hello" style="font-size:24px;color:blue">
        Hello blue text!
    </span>
   ```

   or in javascript:

   ```
    let hello = document.getElementById('hello');
    hello.style.fontSize = '24px';
    hello.style.color = 'blue';
   ```
2. In a `<style>` node:

   ```
    <style>
        #hello {
            font-size: 24px;
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
   ```
3. Linked from an external CSS file:

   ```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hello.css" />
   ```

All are valid. What you use will depend on what you need.

There are some development teams or work environments that may have rules of what you can and cannot use such as banning styles on elements (thereby banning setting styles directly with javascript) but those are opinions. To know why they made such rules you'll have to ask the people who made those rules (and if I were to elaborate my opinion in this answer I can write a small book).

Answer (score -1):

You can define variables in your CSS `:root`:

```
:root {
    --custom_color: #0085ff;
}
```

and then access them with the var() function:

```
a.link {
    var(--custom_color);
}
```

For more information, you can read **this** about CSS variable usage on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp).

You can also edit the variables in your CSS `:root` with Javascript like this:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--var', 'value');

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--custom_color', '#ff8500');
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough solution. Unfortunately, I am relying on a preset palette defined in a .ts file, which I am calling in my various .svelte files. I maintain this preference since I do not want to redefine my palette for every single page, and I can just import that typescript file to get the appropriate colors.

Comment: @fluidnumericsgarrett: Defining the colors in TS is the first mistake, it couples them to the realm of JS when they should be defined in CSS as suggested since presentation/styling is its responsibility.